# How dd will write data on to disk

Tags: dd

```
$ dd if=BIN of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1k seek=1; sync

39+0 records in

39+0 records out

39936 bytes (40 kB, 39 KiB) copied, 0.000348317 s, 115 MB/s
```

I am little confused here how `dd`is writing to disk from start to size, I thought total size could be 1024(1k) bytes and since I used seek=1 the 1*1024 means start would be also 1024.

And summary start with block 1024 to total count of 1024 bytes but it is showing 40K, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a count so dd read the full input. Specify the count, e.g.,

```
dd if=BIN of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1k count=1 seek=1; sync
```

This should write one block of size 1k. (Also, just to note the seek is causing dd to skip the first 1024 bytes - is that intended, required?)

Comment: OK, does this mean it start from 1K and write 40K bytes?